# XCUITest integration with TestRail

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest, testrail

Currently working on integrating my UITest-run results into TestRail, so after every test run it marks my tests as Pass\Fail in testrail.

The idea I have is:

1. In CI create a "pre-build" script that will create a test run in testrail.
2. During execution of automation, in test tearDown() get the result of a test(if a test failed or not), save it all into json file. - **here is the first question, how can I get if a test failed?**
3. Once all tests are done, run a "post-build" script to get updated json file and send request to test rail(which will mark pass\fail tests)

**Anyone who already worked on this, does it sound right for you?
Any advice?**

example of the test:

```
import XCTest

class MyUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        appEntry.app.launch()
        dismissSystemAlerts()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func test_Elements() {
        // MARK: Sample test
        // my test actions are here
    }
}
```

Comment: I've worked out this, but please provide some example code.

Comment: If I got you right, here's how my UITest look like(updated my question with sample)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I implemented.
First I have pre-build script in my CI that will create new Test Run in TestRail. And then UITestObserver will send APIs to TR to update statuses.

new class that I've added:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

class UITestObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
    // Handle Test Case Failure
    public func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase,
                         didFailWithDescription description: String,
                         inFile filePath: String?,
                         atLine lineNumber: Int) {
        var testCaseId: [String] = []
        if let MyTestCaseID = testCase as? BaseTest { testCaseId = MyTestCaseID.inegrateTestRailId() }
        if testCaseId != ["NA"] {
            postTestRailAddResultAPI(for: testCase, testCaseId: testCaseId, description: description)
        }
    }

    // Handle Test Case Pass
    public func testCaseDidFinish(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
        let testRun = testCase.testRun!
        let verb = testRun.hasSucceeded
        var testCaseId: [String] = []
        if let MyTestCaseID = testCase as? BaseTest { testCaseId = MyTestCaseID.inegrateTestRailId() }
        if verb == true && testCaseId != ["NA"] {
            postTestRailAddResultAPI(for: testCase, testCaseId: testCaseId, description: "PASS")
    }
}
```

In BaseTest setUp added this line:

```
XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(UITestObserver())
```

And implemented function postTestRailAddResultAPI that sends actual requests to update status.
All my tests now have `testCaseId` which stores value of `TestRail TestCase number`, and this is how it knows which TCs to update.

Comment: can you point me into the right direction on what did you used for `postTestRailAddResultAPI` or if you wrote the implementation somewhere I would like to take a look. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do,

1. Run tests using scan plugin of fastlane
2. Generate a junit format result
3. Parse the xml and get results of each test
4. Post it to our test case management tool

Kindly share your solution with all of us.